# Loading a SKScene from a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

We're working on a small game where we needed to put a UITableView to summarize the highest scores, but when it comes to load back a SKScene from the said UITableView the app suddenly stops (no crashes or errors in the console, it just stops and freezes), is there a way to bypass this? The high score section is loaded from the Home scene, the same Home scene I'm trying to reach from the high score tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide code?
Make sure there is no breakpoint triggered that may stops your code while running.

And a recommendation From my experience - you should try to avoid combination between UIKit and SpriteKit, this will solve you allot of problems. There are many open source libraries (here is [one](https://github.com/hilogames/HLSpriteKit)) that helps build UI components out of SKNodes.

Comment: I just posted a new answer providing code. I hope it's more clear now!

Comment: These are 4 lines of code, I am afraid it would not be enough.
I can only guess that there is an issue with the GameViewController's SKView staying alive at the point you move to the scores view controller.
Try to clean the SKView (in my game i am removing the SKView from the VC and set it to nil) and build it once again when moving back from the scores view controller.